# How do we manage active directory without windows

Tags: active-directory

I have an Active directory domain controller (Basically AWS managed AD service)
I want to manage users on it but looks like the only way to do it is start a windows box, add it to the domain and manage AD users. We don't need windows for anything else. Is there a way to avoid this windows box and manage this AD users with some kind of web app I can run on a linux box? (We use AD for the VPN)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use any LDAP based tool on the linux system for managing users in your AD domain; the only primary condition is that you should be able to communicate with your AD domain controller(s) on the required ports - 389, 636, etc.

There are dozens of tools available, and you can find several links which talks about the same on Internet:

1. https://serverfault.com/questions/68738/linux-active-directory-tool -- Apache's Directory Studio
2. http://www.linux-magazine.com/Issues/2013/152/adtool -- ADTool

Comment: Thanks I tried apache's directory studio. I can see users list. Any thoughts on how I can set passwords like I can in windows AD tools?

Comment: @Maruthi - I have never worked on Apache Directory Studio, so I can't directly help. Please try to explore if you see any option to modify/change the password of the users (I believe it'd be easy to achieve).